# Dynamically change the custom URL scheme for IOS applications

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to dynamically change the custom URL scheme for an ios application at runtime? I could only find information on how to define custom schemes statically (i.e., the custom scheme is predefined in a configuration file) and I wonder if this can be done dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Even in my case, the url scheme will be provided from web services and i have to dynamically use it to open other app from my app. Is this doable now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot change custom url dynamically. Custom url scheme is part of `Info.plist` file contained in the application bundle. The application bundle is read only. You cannot write to/modify the files contained within the application bundle dynamically.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is this same even now? Even in my case, the url scheme will be provided from web services and i have to dynamically use it to open other app from my app. Is this doable now?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Amar, you can not change custom URL scheme dynamically. Custom scheme is unique every application. So why you need this to open one of multiple app. I dont understand this. You have to be specific while opening one app.

Comment: This is for a research paper we're working on - so no its not a feature that I would expect anyone to use in practice